# Using LINQ query in model (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, controller

I am creating a web application, is it possible to use LINQ queries in the Model ,instead of using it in the Controller?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean at view? Because the model is a class you pass to it. It just keeps data not more. Nevertheless you are not restricted from using LINQ anywhere you want as it's just a set of extension methods.

Comment: Not at view, I want to use it in model class

Comment: you can use it in any class. But in my oppinion, using any manipulations on data inside of model class is a bad design decision almost in every case

Comment: @ILya: only if you are using anemic models. Nothing prevents you from encapsulating model-specific logic in the model. It's a class not a data storage unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use LINQ queries in the model.

Here is an example :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
.
.
.
public class PostRepository
{
    DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

    public IQueryable<Post> FindByParentId(int parentId)
    {
        return from post in db.Posts
               where post.ParentID == parentId
               select post;
    }
```

Comment: @user841852: LINQ queries are no different in a model than in any other code. Any example of a linq query will work in a model as well as in a controller or view or windows app or anything else...

Comment: And how repository is related to the model?

Comment: @ssx What is IPostRepository here?

Comment: @user841852 it's an interface, but you can just skip it for the example

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use your LINQ queries in repository class.

Then you use your Repository methods inside your controller.

Lets say I have a repository class by the name of "CreateRepository" and this is my Createcontroller:

```
 public class CreateController : Controller
    {
        CreateRepository CreateRepository = new CreateRepository();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var ListOfAllUserNames = CreateRepository.GetAllUserNames();

            // etc etc 
            return View();
        }
```

And this is my CreateRepository Class:

```
public class CreateRepository
 {   

   public List<User> GetAllUserNames()
       {
          return db.User.OrderBy(f => f.Username).ToList();
       }
 }
```

This is a example on what I mentioned above.

Comment: Your answer make more sense.